# Trying to migrate from advantage database to firedac

Tags: database, delphi, firedac

I've created a new `VCL` app. On the form I have placed a `DBGrid`, a `Datasource`, an `FDTable`, a `PhysADSDriverLink` and an `FDConnection`.In the database I have placed a `CDX` table `called events.dbf` and its index file (`events.cdx`). Also a button with an OnClick event to open the table.

In PhysADSDriverLink1 I have set the `BaseDriverID to ADS` and `VendorLib to .\ace32.dll`

In the `FDConection1` I have set `DriverName to ADS` and in Params I have set:
    Database to     .\
    ServerTypes to  Local
    TableTypes to   CDX

```
in FDTable i have set:
Connection to 'FDConnection1'
TableName to events
```

If I set FDConnection Connected to true, there is no error
If I set FDTable Active to true, I get an error 5041- the requested object was not found.events -link object is not supported on free connection. This also occurs if I run the app and click the button.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Database` should be an absolute path. You can use [`$(RUN)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Path_Variables_(FireDAC)) for the application path.

Comment: Many thanks! Things are now proceeding apace.